# Solution to Primal-Dual Optimization Problems

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization

I know that I must be wrong, but I'm hoping someone may be able to tell me where my understanding of the problem breaks down in the following question. If we consider the primal problem,

$$\min c^{T}x$$
$$\text{subject to } Ax=b$$

and its corresponding dual problem,

$$\max b^{T}y$$
$$\text{subject to } A^{T}y+s=c$$

then the following optimization problem can be solved by solving the following system of equations,

$$Ax-b=0$$
$$A^{T}y+s-c=0$$
$$b^{T}y-c^{T}x=0$$

where the final equation states that the duality gap must be zero. Wouldn't such a problem easily be solved by some simple linear algebra, since we have 3 unknowns $(x,y,s)$ and 3 equations?

Comment: How do you know that $\ker A \subset \ker c^T$.

Comment: Could you explain the significance of that, this is likely where my understanding breaks down.

Comment: How do you know the primal has a solution?

Comment: I don't, however if it did wouldn't we be able to find it using linear algebra?

Comment: The problem really boils down to characterising $\ker A$ and solving $Ax=b$.